# Facebook notification encoding

Tags: facebook-graph-api, asp.net-mvc-4

When using Facebook Graph API to send some notification to my users, it delivers scrambled to them, like so:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/8ZvFT.png]

**Here is my code:**

```
public void sendFBNotificationByUserID(Guid userID, string msg, string url)
{
    try
    {
        // Facebook information from the user
        FacebookUser fbUser = getFacebookUserByUserID(userID);

        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            // Retrieve "App Access Token" from Facebook
            string appAccessToken = wc.DownloadString("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" + Global.fbAppID + "&client_secret=" + Global.fbAppSecret + "&grant_type=client_credentials");

            // Create POST parameters
            string POSTparam = "template=" + msg + "&href=" + url + "&" + appAccessToken;

            // POST to Facebook Graph API to send notification
            wc.UploadString("https://graph.facebook.com/" + fbUser.facebookID + "/notifications/", POSTparam);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

Any idea?

**EDIT:**

I did a little reading about `URL Encoding` and this code solved my problem:

```
msg = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(msg);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be because of the encoding of your page. Some characters get scrambled if they aren't encoded properly. Maybe try using UTF-8 or something else. 
Best I could think of.

Comment: All strings in C#.NET are encoded in UTF-16, so could this be Facebook's fault?